# Android Studio sqlite update

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I have made a sqlite table where I can insert data for my Trip app. I'm trying to update the rows, but I can't figure it out. I have searched alot but I'm doing something wrong on the update part and I don't know what.

```
public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "triptracker.db";
public static final String TABLE_NAME = "trip_table";
public static final String COL_1 = "trip_id";
public static final String COL_2 = "trip_title";
public static final String COL_3 = "trip_description";
public static final String COL_4 = "trip_image";
public static final String COL_5 = "trip_location";
```

When I am inserting data:

```
public boolean insertData(String title, String description, String location) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(COL_2, title);
        contentValues.put(COL_3, description);
        // contentValues.put(COL_4, image);
        contentValues.put(COL_5, location);
        long result = db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, contentValues);
        if (result == -1)
            return false;
        else
            return true;

    }


//When I'm updating the database

public boolean update(String title, String description, String location){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(COL_2, title);
        contentValues.put(COL_3, description);
        contentValues.put(COL_5, location);
        db.update(TABLE_NAME,contentValues, "location=?", new String[]{location} );
        return true;

    }

// I need to press a button in order to save the data
        saveItem.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new MenuItem.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {

              if(!editLocation.getText().toString().equals("") && !editTitle.getText().toString().equals("") && !editDescription.getText().toString().equals("")){
                    boolean insert = myDb.update(editLocation.getText().toString(),
                            editDescription.getText().toString(),
                            editTitle.getText().toString());
                }
                else {
                    Toast.makeText(singlemomentactivity.this, "Your moment is not added ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                }
```

Comment: Sorry can you explain it more? What problem you are facing.

Comment: update your data by assigning auto increment id to it @Number70

Comment: @JawadAhmed, updating isn't working. When I press on the save button the app is crashing.

Comment: @BrahmaDatta, I just started learning SQL last week. Can you maybe give me an example?

Comment: Sure ill make an answer @Number70

Comment: @BrahmaDatta, thank you very much.

Comment: recheck your edit text data.There might be null pointer exceptions. if there is no problem I will write an example @Number70

Comment: @BrahmaDatta, I get the SQLiteException.```android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: location (code 1 SQLITE_ERROR[1]): , while compiling: UPDATE trip_table SET trip_title=?,trip_description=?,trip_location=? WHERE location=?```

Comment: Probably, COL_5 is "location" but that column does not exist. When you add columns, they are not automatically created in the app database because they were created on first time you open your app. Easiest way to fix is uninstall/install you app. Then, the database will be re-created. Just be sure the column "location" is created during onCreate()

Comment: Is there a column `location` in the table? If you added the column after you first tan the app, uninstall the app from the device and rerun.

Comment: If you want to update a row in the table you pass 3 column values that you want to be updated. So far so good. Which row will be updated? How will you find it? By `location`? Is there such a column? The error says no. If you want to find the row by using another column, you must pass a 4th parameter to the method `update()`   with that column's value.

Comment: @forpas, I want to update 3 columns, title description and location. There are such columns and the error is fixed now. How can I pass the 4th parameter?

Comment: How do you want to find the row to update? With which column's value? Is there some id?

Comment: @forpas, yes COL_1 = trip_id, with a string value.

Comment: See the code in my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass the trip_id column's value as a parameter:

```
public boolean update(String tripid, String title, String description, String location){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(COL_2, title);
    contentValues.put(COL_3, description);
    contentValues.put(COL_5, location);
    return db.update(TABLE_NAME,contentValues, COL_1 + " = ?", new String[]{tripid}) > 0;
}
```

and call the method:

```
boolean insert = myDb.update(
  <pass the id's value here>,
  editTitle.getText().toString(),
  editDescription.getText().toString(),
  editLocation.getText().toString()
);
```

I changed the order of the parameters because it was wrong in your code.
Also your `update()` method will return `true` if the row is updated with the condition `> 0`

Comment: <pass the id's value here>, you mean DatabaseHelper.COL_1? If i do it like this:                    ```boolean insert = myDb.update(DatabaseHelper.COL_1, editLocation.getText().toString(),
                            editDescription.getText().toString(),
                            editTitle.getText().toString());``` it is still not updating

Comment: No I mean to pass a value like "1" which is the id of the row that you want to be updated.

Comment: yes true. It is working but it is doing a little bit of strange things. I have a listview where the data is being added and for example I change the description, the title is changing.

Comment: Your code passed the arguments in the wrong order to update(). The correct order is: tripid, title, description, location.

Comment: oh I see now. Yhank you very much but I have 1 question left. The point is I have 5 different data in my listview. What happens now is for example I edit the description in my row 5. What happens is that it is changing row 1. How can I fix this? Also thank you very much.. It is helping my out

Comment: Is there a case that you don't pass the correct id so the wrong row is updated?

Comment: if I dont pass anything so (trip_id "", ...) nothing will be updated

Comment: You must pass the id of the row that you want to update. When you read the rows from the table to display them in the ListView, you also get the id of each row. When you want to update a row you must pass that id as the 1st argument to your update() method. There is no other way.

Comment: oh okay, I need to add a edittext then to enter the id. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Try this, maybe the key reference is the issue. But let me know after you try this.

```
public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "triptracker.db";
 public static final String TABLE_NAME = "trip_table";
public static final String COL_1 = "trip_id";
public static final String COL_2 = "trip_title";
public static final String COL_3 = "trip_description";
public static final String COL_4 = "trip_image";
public static final String COL_5 = "trip_location";
public static final String COL_6 = "ID";


//oncreate method of SQLite DB

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

    //Create Search Table

    String EXAMPLE_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME + "("
            + COL_6 + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"
            + COL_1 + " TEXT UNIQUE,"
            + COL_2 + " TEXT,"
            + COL_3 + " TEXT,"
            + COL_4 + " TEXT,"
            + COL_5 + " TEXT,"
            + ")";

    db.execSQL(EXAMPLE_TABLE);
  }


public boolean update(String title, String description, String location){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(COL_2, title);
    contentValues.put(COL_3, description);
    contentValues.put(COL_5, location);

     //code for only if location is updated
     if(//location needs to be updated){

      ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
            values.put(COL_5,location);
            db.update(SarathCityLocalDatabase.EXAMPLE_TABLE,values,COL_6 + " = ?",new String[]{location});
     }
    return true;

}
```

Comment: It doesn't give an error anymore but it doesn't save it also when I press the save button.

Comment: check the new edit. I just added the ID for each row and thereby you can update the value by using its ID. you don't need the location item name again @Number70

Answer (score 1):

Try updating this line:

```
db.update(TABLE_NAME,contentValues, "location=?", new String[]{location} );
```

For this:

```
db.update(TABLE_NAME,contentValues, "trip_location=?", new String[]{location} );
```

Comment: new String[]{trip_location} cant resolve symbol trip_location

Comment: db.update(TABLE_NAME,contentValues, "trip_location=?", new String[]{location} );